# Facebook SDK in android application

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Hi I am trying to use facebook sdk in my android app. I have imported the facebook sdk that I have downloaded here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk. After I imported the sdk there are other folders imported with it, FriendPickerSample, HelloFacebookSample, PlacePickerSample, RPSSample, Scrumptious, SDKTest, StatusActivity and SwitchUserSample. Is all those folders necessary. Any commnet would be appreciated.

Comment: As their names say, they are just Samples, you can run them and see how they work. but they are not necessary

Comment: Don't post ever these kind of questions it's just time waste first of all go to the developers link and then find out what is necessary and then ask some help BTW its not necessary these are the working example of Facebook sdk you can say just for learning the did attach sample codes.

Comment: It's a valid question as, at least on Android Studio, they cannot be easily deleted.

Answer (score 1):

no they are not necessary , since they are only for your reference . Use it you know the facebook sdk better